# Зависание базы данных при загрузке большого объёма данных и попытке повторого подключения к ней

Tags: java, mysql, sql, база-данных, h2

Я записываю большой объём данных в БД с помощью программы, после успешной записи данных все connection, открытые для записи, закрываются и возвращаются в пул. Это проверено.

Дальше я перезапускаю программу для записи данных в БД, для повторной записи и программа зависает навечно, т.к. взяв свободный connection из пула уже не может выполнять нужный оператор SQL на нём, похоже. Происходит какая-то блокирвока потока к ресурсу в базе и осободить потоки получается только при удалении БД.

При маленьком объёме данных такого бесконечного зависания не происходит. Так же не происходит зависания, пока не перезапустишь программу. Поток зависает при первом же обращении к базе только после перезагрузки.

Встречался ли кто-то с такой же проблемой? Прошу помочь или хотя бы объяснить принцип работы бд в этом направлении, чтобы я мог отладить это сам.

На скриншоте предоставлен стэктрейс места, где зависает поток[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каком месте программа зависает? Это можно узнать посмотрев stacktrace в момент зависания

Comment: И какая все-таки СУБД? В метках и h2 и mysql

Comment: Ту же операцию которую пробуете делать из программы, когда она "зависает" из другого клиента удается выполнить? Т.е. это проблема конкретной программы или из любого клиента так же?

Comment: База данныз h2, включен режим поддержки синтаксиса sql.

Программа зависает, после того. как получила свободный коннекшен и попыталась выполнить на нём оператор чтения sql

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос про конкретное место. Это операция чтения из сокета или ожидание на каком-то мониторе? Покажите стектрейс, одним словом.

Comment: h2 используется в каком режиме (в памяти или сервер)? Ответы и уточнения вносите в текст вопроса кнопкой "править".

Comment: покажите метод, который записывает данные

Comment: Я извиняюсь, не могу предоставлять код данной программы.

Но метод записи данных весьма тревиален. вызывается стандартный метод у класса SQLConnection - .batch(query, res), query - список запросов, res - асинхронный обработчик завершения метода. Он вызывается после завершения выполнения запросов и в нём закрывается текущий connection.

Answer (score 1):

В некоторых случаях размер данных для одного batch может быть насколько большой, что его было бы удобнее разделить на несколько подбатчей. Это можно сделать вручную, например разбив коллекцию на несколько частей или лучше поручить Spring JDBC. Для использования subbatch необходимо реализовать (да да, ещё один) интефейс ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter. В отличие от BatchPreparedStatementSetter он типизируется конкретным объектом и самостоятельно не управляет размером batch’а.

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
ADD_QUERY,
orders,
BATCH_SIZE,
new OrderSetter());
```

в URL необходимо добавить ?rewriteBatchedStatements=true